# Has HTC Sync 3 dropped support for Windows 7 Contacts?

Tags: htc-desire, contacts, sync, windows, htc-sync-3.0

I've got an HTC Desire and since I got it, I've been synchronising the contacts on my phone with the "Contacts" folder in Windows 7 using HTC Sync 2.something

I noticed HTC Sync 3 was available, so I uninstalled version 2 and installed version 3, but it only seems to support syncing with contacts in Outlook or Outlook Express.

Am I missing something massively obvious? It seems odd to remove support for a current feature (Windows 7 Contacts) while retaining support for a program (Outlook Express) that hasn't been current since Windows XP.

Answer (score 1):

Quite possibly, the Contacts folder has been [officially deprecated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd371760%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It exists for Vista compatibility where it was introduced for the first time.
I have not yet tested the 3.0 sync app. I am still using 2.x and sync with Outlook.